# Applying seq to improve execution time in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, lazy-evaluation, execution-time, seq

I have the following:

```
data Node = Node { position::Int
                 , zombies::Float
                 , connections::[Int]
                 }

moveZombie :: [Node] -> Node -> Node
moveZombie nodes (Node i _ cx) = zc `seq` Node i zc cx
  where zc = sum [zombies n / (fromIntegral $ length $ connections n) | i <- cx, let n = nodes !! i]

step :: Int -> [Node] -> [Node]
step 0 nodes = nodes
step k nodes = step (k-1) $ map (moveZombie nodes) nodes
```

Compiling with profiling enabled in GHC tells me that the cost centers are:

```
                               Individual
COST CENTRE            MODULE %time %alloc
moveZombie.zc          Main   60.3   90.4
moveZombie.zc.n        Main   37.6    0.0
```

I tried the following: `` moveZombie nodes (Node i _ cx) = zc `seq` Node i zc cx `` to force strict evaluation and have the program run faster, but have been entirely unsuccessful. I know there is something wrong with my understanding of the way `seq` works, but I can't seem to figure out what.

I think, that I need to force strict evaluation on `step k nodes = step (k-1) $ map (moveZombie nodes) nodes` but, I am confused.

**I know that:**

1. `seq a b` forces `a` into the weak first normal form, when evaluating `b`
2. That an expression is in weak normal form if the outermost expression is a lambda or a Data constructor

Any pointers towards what understanding I am missing?

Comment: I think your main problem is `let n = nodes !! i`. List indexing is `O(i)`, so if a `Node` has many connections, a `moveZombie` on that is quadratic in the number of `Node`s. If you have a lot of `Node`s with many connections, you get cubic complexity for a `step`. Try using an `Array` instead of a list. (If you have more than just a handful of `Node`s, it won't improve things if you have only two.)

Comment: I'd personally prefer `Data.Sequence` to `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

The main speed problem is treating 'nodes' as a list - your algorithm often needs to fetch items at random positions, and that is O(n) for every retrieval in a linked list data structure.

Replacing 'nodes' from [Node] to any better suited data structure (Data.Map, or Array) would improve the complexity significantly.